# Specific comparisons with lmer. Contrasts?

Tags: r, statistics, anova, mixed-models

I have a mixed model containing a dependent variable v, two fixed effects g1 and t with the individuals as a random factor rf.

```
fit <- lmer(v ~ g1 + t + (1|rf))
```

In my case of interest the dependent variable v, changes fast with time t and I will test the response of the binary fixed factor g1. Since the response is only seen at one of the time values, the overall statistics for g1 (g1_control or g1_active) are not significant

```
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lme4::lmer(formula = v ~ g1 + t + (1 | rf))

Linear Hypotheses:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
g1_control - g1_active == 0   -91.40      83.87   -1.09    0.276
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

> summary(glht(fit, linfct = mcp(t = 'Tukey')))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lme4::lmer(formula = v ~ g1 + t + (1 | rf))

Linear Hypotheses:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
15 - 0 == 0    716.30     106.30   6.738   <0.001 ***
30 - 0 == 0    312.75     106.30   2.942   0.0172 *  
60 - 0 == 0     73.74     106.30   0.694   0.8995    
30 - 15 == 0  -403.55     106.30  -3.796   <0.001 ***
60 - 15 == 0  -642.56     106.30  -6.045   <0.001 ***
60 - 30 == 0  -239.00     106.30  -2.248   0.1106
```

What I really want to test only is whether g1_active is different from g1_control at the four time points 0 15 30 and 60 with respect to v.

I have an idea it about contrast but the examples I have seen are either to general or to difficult for me to understand.

Anybody who can give me an example to solute this problem

Comment: are your time points discrete? could you fit a separate model for each time point and compare treatments or do you really want to test the interaction effect of g1*time

Comment: Yes my timepoints are discrete (0,15,30,60). There is interaction between g1*t so yes I could do it manualy for each group seperately using for example Dunnett. However this is a problem which happens now and then, so I would like to see if there is a generallt solution

Comment: BTW your suggestion would not help me. What I want to test is g1.active:t.0 vs g1.control:t.0, g1.active:t.15 vs g1.control:t.15 etc.

Comment: would `lsmeans::difflsmeans(fit, "g1:t")` help? It doesn't really get at your question of only grabbing certain contrasts, it just does Tukey contrasts, but it plays nicely with interaction terms. selecting only contrasts with significant results is a slippery slope for reporting

Comment: Comparing g1c.t0 with g1a.t15 would be biological nonsense so the slope is not so slippery indead :-)

Comment: very true, I'm not sure how to get glht to handle interaction terms